# How to customize a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to customize a textbox such that the user will input date as shown in image1 below. Note these points :

1. Apr not 04 or April or anything else.
2. The order must be dd/mmm/yyyy. even if their computer system date is set otherwise.
3. Text to be aligned left. How do i do that textbox in visual basic 2010 ?

[image: Image1]

Comment: Why a textbox and not a date control?

Comment: Any can do so long as it will appear as shown. Will it be customizable like that?

Comment: `Will it be customizable like that`  Yes: http://i.imgur.com/nZFURRP.jpg

Comment: Do you mean a DateTimePicker? I had tried but 1. It is inheriting system date-time settings and 2. It is always displaying todays date and i wanted it to be blank.

Comment: I have managed but the first character is hiden a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think a [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) with a custom format will be the right option for you. So that you can restrict the user to enter digits for month and letters for day and year. you can set the mask like the following:

```
txtCustomDate.Mask = "00/LLL/0000"
```

Where `0` stands for integer `L` for Letter, required. Restricts input to the ASCII letters a-z and A-Z. This mask element is equivalent to [a-zA-Z] in regular expressions.

You may get better format options from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx)